# Inline editing with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Are there any guidelines on doing 'inline' editing with jQuery?

I know I am not using the correct term here, but basically you click on a some text and dynamically the area changes to an editable input box with a submit button.

Is there any built in capabilities with jQuery?

Answer (score 8):

jQuery has nothing built-in as far as I know, but check out [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), which is a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="someText" id="editableText" class="hideBorder"/>

$('#editableText').toggle(function() {
             $(this).removeClass('hideBorder');
          }, function() {
             $(this).addClass('hideBorder');
          });

.hideBorder {
 border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [inedit](http://webolitic.com/inedit/) jquery plugin